# One node causing entire Galera Cluster to remain in bad state

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a production MariaDB Galera 5 node cluster that has been running for about 8 months at our factory. One node had a powerfail / un-graceful shutdown (Ubuntu 16.04) and since then if that node is up, it causes the entire cluster to permanently respond with "wsrep has not yet prepared node for application use". If I shut down that node and restart the cluster, all is fine. My suspicion is the ungraceful shutdown caused some file system issues that cause the entire cluster to be unusable. Just curious if anyone else has seen this.

Comment: Please post MariaDB err log and system log (filesystem checks?). It looks like the member is not properly joined into the cluster. Please also post your Galera config (what SST method you use and the SST logs from mysql err log)

Comment: Consider buying another node and add it to the cluster.